# Populate an entire column based off selection from a drop down list in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I created a drop-down list through data validation of the 50 states.

I want to select a state from that drop-down and populate an entire separate column full of that states counties. I have a table on a separate worksheet that has columns "State" and "County" as A and B respectively. column A has the state name the entire length of the counties in column B.

I have searched for about 2 hours through the internet and cannot seem to pinpoint one best way. Any help would be great

Comment: what you mean by "entire length of the counties in column B" ? all the counties are in the same cell  for each state?

Comment: @GowthamShiva as in if there are 10 rows in column B, the state name would be listed 10 times, once per row, in column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Column A` contains the states. `Column C` and `D` contains the states and the counties respectively.

Cell `F1` has data validation drop down for the range `$A$1:$A$14`. Enter the formula in column G and drag down, or enter the formula for the entire column,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("C"&MATCH($F$1,C:C,0)+ROW()-ROW($1:$1)&":D999"),MATCH($F$1,INDIRECT("C"&MATCH($F$1,C:C,0)+ROW()-ROW($1:$1)&":C999"),0),2),"")
```

[image]

If you have the county names in a separate sheet modify the formula accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! now to modify this to my exisiting problem! :)

Comment: @TrevLawson Thats great. please upvote if you found this useful